# Best way to assign json data to jquery

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to use the two options below..

1) I generate one json file (file size is 9mb) and call this file on load time.

```
$.get(JsonFilePath, function (data) {
  var databaseTable = $.parseJSON(data);
})
```

This method is taking 30s+ time on load time

2) Here I am calling one function that generates json and I call this function on load time.

```
 $.get(functionPath, function (data) {
  var databaseTable = $.parseJSON(data);
})
```

php function code

```
add_action('wp_ajax_GetAllRecord', 'GetAllRecord');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetAllRecord','GetAllRecord');
function GetAllRecord()
{
global $wpdb;  
$test_switchnew_btl_data =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."btl_data");
$test_switchnew_residental_data =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."residental_data");
$switchnew_lenderprofile =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."lenderprofile");

echo json_encode(array('switchnew_btl_data' => json_encode($test_switchnew_btl_data),  'switchnew_residental_data' => json_encode($test_switchnew_residental_data), 'switchnew_lenderprofile' => json_encode($switchnew_lenderprofile)));

}
```

But this process is also taking 30s+ time to load. Because the database has 14k records.

Can you please help me to find best way to decrease loading time?

Comment: Add limit in your query

Comment: @dipmala this project is mostly working on front-side. filter all result from user-input base so I need all data to-gather on load time.

Comment: filter your result when it is needed. Means. don't load all data at once just load the data with ajax the user wants to see. Another thing: 30s for 14k records? Try to optimate your database with an index and try to find out why you database is so slow.